# Is this Python Module in Windows?

Tags: python, module, python-2.7, easy-install

Are the following packages part of the standard installation of Python 2.7?

```
import common
import settings
import xpath
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, these are not, check the python 2.7 [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/)

EDIT: xpath could be the one [here](http://code.google.com/p/py-dom-xpath/). It's hard to answer exactly without knowing the context, but i have no knowledge of common modules/packages named settings / common.

Comment: where can I install those module ?

Comment: common and settings module is weired module. otherwise, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

No, those modules are not found in the [stdlib](http://docs.python.org/library/index.html).